# navigation has link dots

Tags: hyperlink, navigation, tags, overriding

HELP AN OLD WOMAN SOLVE THIS PUZZLE!!! I'm redesigning a css website from my 50th high school reunion to the 55th.  When I first designed this site in 2013, dreamweaver offered spry navigation which doesn't work now.  So I changed to a CSS navigation and can't get the link bullets off the navigation blocks.  I've been working on this problem for a week.

the site is: http://www.northbergen1963.com  I've tried text-decoration: none in several places but nothing works.  Not even with "important" added.

Comment: I found out why the text is red and solved the problem.  I still cannot get the link bullets off the navigation.